# Event bubbling JQuery FullCalendar + Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, event-bubbling

I'm currently making an application with Backbone.js and some JQuery libraries.
Today I work on a Calendar using [JQuery FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and I have a little problem :

If I click on day then close the form then click on an other day then I close etc... then I submit the form. I sent that form much of event clicked.

What I'm doing wrong ? This is my [code](https://gist.github.com/0de8fe98ce80bc2d06c2).

Please give me a way to fix it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by exiting submit event out from the JQuery FullCalendar events.
Now my code look like [this](https://gist.github.com/0de8fe98ce80bc2d06c2).